# AJAX request doesn't seem to recieve the response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

I have the following code:
AJAX:

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "mail.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {first_name:first_name,last_name:last_name,email: email,telephone:telephone,message:message},
                cache: 'false',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    {
                        if(response.status==1)
                            alert('Email sent!');
                        else
                            alert('Error.')
                    }
                }
            });
```

PHP:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$to="me@example.com";
$message=$_POST['message']."\r\n"."\r\n".$_POST['first_name'].' '.$_POST['last_name']."\r\n".$_POST['telephone'];
$subject="New Message!";
$email=$_POST['email'];
$headers="From:".$email;
$success=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
if($success)
{
    $done=array("status"=>true);
    echo json_encode($done);
}
else
{
    $done=array("status"=>false);
    echo json_encode($done);
}
```

In the network panel, it seems like the response is not recieved and the type is "Pending"

Comment: Why not just try: if(response.status) ?

Comment: Not as a part of "success"? Or what do you mean?

Comment: You should check the PHP, try to return/echo something without sending mail.

Comment: You are storing your bool in the array, then checking if it matches 1 in your success statement. Why not just check if it matches the bool statement straight up?

`success: function(response) {
                {
                    if(response.status)
                        alert('Email sent!');...`

Comment: you have extra curly brace inside success function

Comment: please var_dump($_POST); in the php and inspect with firebug or something.  I suspect you are posting json, and $_POST does not decode json for you.

Comment: Yes, it does. The problem is that the mail is sent properly, however no response is recieved.

Comment: Try using firebug or firefox or chrome dev extension(F12) to check what response it is returning

Comment: Exactly what I am saying is that NO RESPONSE is returned. It was a php error anyway

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, this

```
 success: function(response) {
                {
                    if(response.status==1)
                        alert('Email sent!');
                    else
                        alert('Error.')
                }
            }
```

should be

```
  success: function(response) {
                    if(response.status==1)
                        alert('Email sent!');
                    else
                        alert('Error.');
            }
```